# Loading image in updateprogress stuck asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

I have updatepanel and updateprogress in master page.
One Search button in content page that post back to server.
page is working fine in browser.

but in android app that calls the page(I don't know how they call the page) 
when search button click
updateprogress work in first time .
second time loadingimage in updateprogress is stuck.

please help.